# How to manipulate query result in PHP to repeat first row

Tags: php, mysql

How can i echo the first row of a query result 2 or more times, outside and inside of the while loop?

The following code just echo the first row outside of loop and doesn't allow to echo again inside of loop

```
case '1':
      $db->Query("SELECT titulo_video,subtitulo_video,youtube_id,nome_norma FROM videos");
      echo "<h2>" . $db->Row()->nome_norma . "</h2>";
      while ($row = $db->Row()) {
        echo "<h3>" . $row->titulo_video . "</h3>";
        echo "<p>" . $row->subtitulo_video . "</p>";
      }
      break;
```

I want the data as follows:

```
    <h3>row 1 - colum 1</h3>

    <h2>row1 - colum 2</h2>    
    <p>row 1 - colum 3</p>

    <h2>row2 - colum 2</h2>    
    <p>row 2 - colum 3</p>

    <h2>row3 - colum 2</h2>    
    <p>row 4 - colum 3</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fiddle with the loops a bit.

```
if ($row = $db->Row ())
{
    echo '<h2>' ...;
    do
    {
        echo '<h3>' ...;
        echo '<p>' ...;
    } while ($row = $db->Row ());
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. For reference: [PHP do-while loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

Comment: I think it is conceptually cleaner (and easier to read) than a sentinel value and also doesn't need the extra test everywhere iteration.

Comment: A sentinel value is a perfectly acceptable approach, but it requires the test every iteration (which may or may not be an issue), an extra variable, and uses the value 0 for the beginning rather than just placing the code that uses it at the beginning. Sentinels become more better than my solution if the number is actually used for something else, or if there are other special cases, like inserting a header in between (maybe an ad, even) every N rows.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explained well. I need to repeat the first row two times, 1st for the first column and another for the 2nd column inside of loop

Comment: And that is actually what happens. Try it out.

The first time you load $row, (in the `if` statement) it is used for the header, then enters the loop, where you basically reuse it. And only *after* that, does the next row get loaded. The `do ... while` loop ends when no new rows are loaded.

Comment: I have tried your code and it partially fits my issue, but the second row isn't showed. i can get rows 1,3,5,6... I think the first row replaces the second one. Have any sugestion?

Comment: There's no way that can happen if the code is used as is. I hope you haven't added any more calls to `$db->Row()` in there anywhere... post the updated code so we can see.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much. I had a one call to $db->Row() in excess

Answer (score 1):

Make use a **[Sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)**:

```
  $i = 0;
  while ($row = $db->Row()) {
    echo "<h3>" . $row->titulo_video . "</h3>";
    echo "<p>" . $row->subtitulo_video . "</p>";
    if($i==0){
       echo "<h3>" . $row->titulo_video . "</h3>";
       echo "<p>" . $row->subtitulo_video . "</p>"; 
    }
   $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to treat the first row differently, handle it entirely outside of the loop, rather than including a conditional in your while loop, it's cleaner to handle it like this:

```
$first_row = $db->Row();
echo "<h2>" . $first_row->nome_norma . "</h2>";
echo "<h3>" . $first_row->titulo_video . "</h3>";
echo "<h3>" . $first_row->subtitulo_video . "</h3>";

while ($row = $db->Row()) {
  echo "<h3>" . $row->titulo_video . "</h3>";
  echo "<p>" . $row->subtitulo_video . "</p>";
}
break;
```